# Conveniently make all movie textures play

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So, I have a scene with multiple movie textures playing simultaneously, and I cannot get them all to play in the viewport (as the only way I know of to get one to play at all in the viewport is to have the UV/Image editor open, and also to be in Texture or Material shading view).

However, (and I may be wrong about this), it seems as if they will not all play during the final render either—a far larger concern.

I'd appreciate an answer to this troubling dilemma. How do I get all of my movie textures to play simultaneously in the final render, and if possible in the viewport as well?

EDIT: This is a very simple setup, simply consisting of a few materials with a movie file placed into an image texture plugged into the diffuse of a principled BSDF.

Comment: Showing planes or other objects textured separately with different movies in the 3D viewport is simply a matter of texturing each in the usual way, and running the animation. (ATL-A) All should play similtaneously as though separate video monitors.  In the texture properties-->Image tab, make sure the 'Auto Refresh' & also 'perhaps 'Cyclic' boxes, are ticked.  For previews, render using OpenGL until you get it right. They will render in a fraction of the time compared to Cycles.

Comment: @Edgel3D I've done all of that already, only the video file open in the UV/Image editor will play in the viewport. I'm a bit more concerned with the final render, though. Except "separate video monitors." are you implying that I need a multi-monitor setup to solve the viewport issue?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: @Cegaton it's a very simple setup that is used in numerous sorts of projects, added the information to the question.

Comment: @Edgel3D Thank you, but unfortunately (as the tags indicate) I'm using Cycles, which seems to function differently.

Comment: @Legoman you also mentioned you couldn't see more than one video operating in the 3D(?) viewport.  Hence the video.  Not a problem.  Hope you get around this.